# Azure CDN Premium Verizon - Fixing 404s with URL Rewrite

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, single-page-application, azure-cdn

Been already 3 days on this, can't wrap my head around it.

I'm hosting an Angular app as a static website on Azure Storage and making it available through Azure CDN.

### The problem

Loading or reloading any page that is not the home page returns a 404 for the document (only)

### My attempts

I've already changed the default 404 document to index.html, but I noticed that reloading still returns a 404, even if content is loaded properly :(

So I created a new URL Rewrite rule (using the Premium Verizon tier) to make this fallback happen. This is my last attempt, not dissimilar from the previous ones (all working on regexr, regex101 and others for PCRE):

```
IF Request Header Regex Name=`User-Agent` Does Not Match `ECPurge\/*`
        URL Rewrite -> Source      <endpoint> `(^(?!.*\.(svg|ico|webp|otf|ttf|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg)($|\?)).*$)`
                       Destination <endpoint> `index.html`
```

[URL Rewrite rule for index.html fallback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnd3q.png) (image)

Basically I'm trying to make the rewrite happen only for app routes and not for assets and js files.

**This rule though appears to not change the behaviour of the cdn in any way**, as I still get 404s on a page reload. I also confirmed this by placing an actual 404.html file as a 404 default document for the static website.

I'm also using a URL rewrite for another rule that uses the same regex pattern for the source, and that rule also seems to do nothing.

I double checked the regex pattern and the results are always correct on the various fiddlers.
But I got a feeling that this regex pattern is not working in some way.

Any suggestions?

**PS** Image for the other broken rule: [Rewrite rule n.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TAWq.png)